# How to start method in background after spring app starts

Tags: java, spring, background, initialization

I have method that perform Url scan and I need to initiate it in backround after all spring configurations are loaded. I tryed to use InitializingBean, but process goes to loop not in background and configuration never ends. Please give me any sugession on this issue. Thank you.

```
public class ScheduledScanner implements InitializingBean {

    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ScheduledScanner.class);

    protected final static String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0";

    private static final int MYTHREADS = 30;

    private Date date = new Date();

    private Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

    private AdminService adminService;

    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"classpath:application-context.xml"});

    @Autowired
    public void setAdminService(AdminService adminService) {
        this.adminService = adminService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setEmployeeService(EmployeeService employeeService) {
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }

    /**
     * Sends GET request to @param ip: @param port with Apache HttpClient
     * <p/>
     * param ip      - must contain URL or IP of target server;
     * param port    - for server target Port;
     * param timeout - sets the time for request timeout before no respond;
     * <p/>
     * ServerState enum:
     * OK - server is up and responding correctly
     * WARN  - server is running, but returns a response to the HTTP - code different than 200
     * FAIL - the server is not responding, or responds with HTTP code, such as 500
     * <p/>
     * - all other info: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.Status.html
     */
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

        logger.debug("ServletContextListener started");

        final List<ServerEntity> listToScan = adminService.getAllServers();

        final SystemSettingsModel settings = employeeService.getSettingsByName("default");

        // setting task to execute;
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(MYTHREADS);
ApplicationContext context =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"classpath:application-context.xml"});
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // iterating list of all servers
                for (ServerEntity serverEntity : listToScan) {

                    // check if state of server is active
                    if (serverEntity.getActive().equals(1)) {

                        ServerState state;

                        try {
                            // setting URL or IP eith Port of target address
                            URL obj = new URL(serverEntity.getAddress() + ":" + serverEntity.getPort());

                            // establishing connection
                            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
                            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

                            // setting timeout of response
                            con.setConnectTimeout(settings.getTimeoutOfRespond());

                            // add request header
                            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

                            if (con.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                                state = ServerState.OK;
                            } else if (con.getResponseCode() == 500) {
                                state = ServerState.FAIL;   // Internal Server Error
                            } else {
                                state = ServerState.WARN;   // BAD_REQUEST or other conflict
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            state = ServerState.FAIL;
                        }

                        // saving response from server
                        serverEntity.setState(state);
                        serverEntity.setResponse(state.toString());
                        serverEntity.setLastCheck(timestamp);
                        adminService.updateServer(serverEntity);
                    }   // if
                }   // run()
            }   // for
            /*
             * Scheduling Fixed Rate of scan
             *
             * param initialDelay the time to delay first execution;
             * param period the period between successive executions;
             * param unit the time unit of the initialDelay and period parameters;
             */
        }, 0, settings.getServerScanInterval(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }   // executeScanner()
}
```

in the debug, app start to go in loop this line:

```
(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:preInstantiateSingletons:596) Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@410bf486: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,adminPasswordUpdateController,adminSettingsController,employeeDeleteController,employeeEditController,employeeManagementController,employeeRegistrationController,serverAssignmentController,serverDeleteController,serverEditController,serverManagementController,serverRegistrationController,employeePasswordUpdateController,serverDetailsController,serverMonitoringController,loginLogoutController,passwordRecoveryController,employeeJdbcDaoSupport,serverJdbcDaoSupport,settingsJdbcDaoSupport,AdminServiceImpl,AnonymousServiceImpl,EmployeeServiceImpl,userAuthentication,customUtilsImpl,CustomMailDeliveryImpl,scheduledScanner,simpleScannerImpl,employeeRegistrationValidator,employeeUpdateValidatior,passwordRecoveryValidator,passwordUpdateValidator,serverRegistrationValidator,settingsUpdateValidator,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,txManager,dataSource,org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0,log4jInitialization,mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#1,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
```

**UPDATED:**
I removed @Component annotation and it removed loop in config lines, but method is not looping as it was expected.

This is application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Activates annotations scan, declares support for all the general annotations
        like @Autowired, @Resource, @Required, @PostConstruct-->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Scans for annotated components in base-package -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="serverMonitoring"/>

    <!-- Spring modules -->
    <import resource="classpath:/spring/spring-data-source.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:/spring/spring-logging.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:/spring/spring-mvc.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:/spring/spring-mail.xml"/>


    <bean id="scheduledScanner" class="serverMonitoring.util.network.impl.ScheduledScanner" />

</beans>
```

Still, my scaner does not perform loop with scan as it have to.

Comment: Have you tried putting ScheduledExecutorService scheduler into a Thread of its own?

Comment: @Justin Wrobel, thanks for reply. No I didn't tried that. Can you explain how it works and how it will help me?

Comment: Have you debugged the `afterPropertiesSet` to see what happens? This should work fine.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis thank you for reply. The method is initiated after spring config starts, but lines goes to infinite loop(this is programed procees) but configuration never stops. I thod it will run in buckground after  all config been done.

Comment: @serge Which line exactly goes into unresponsive state in debug mode?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, one second i'll checking.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis,  I updated my post with line on which app start to go in loop

Comment: Show us your application context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. The main problem was in service level wich throwed AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException, so after few days of playing with context and initialisations I changed service level with DAO level and returned @Component annotation.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is blocking somewhere else, not at the `SchedulerExecutorService`. The code below works fine.

```
public static class MyBean implements InitializingBean {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(13);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Hello from scheduler");                 
            }
        }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

} 

@Configuration
public static class Config {
    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
    System.out.println(context.getBean(MyBean.class));
}
```

Comment: Tell me please, how should I configure my class in xml configuration? Is this is correct way:<bean class="serverMonitoring.util.network.impl.ScheduledScanner">
        <property name="methodName" value="afterPropertiesSet"/> or should I just specify path to my class?
    </bean>

Comment: @Serge Get rid of the `property` element. Your class doesn't have a field called `methodName`.

Comment: one more question, where is correct place for my bean definition, in the app-context.xml or in spring-servlet.xml?

Comment: @Serge That depends. The servlet context should hold anything that is only relevant to the servlet. If the servlet doesn't interact with your class, then it should be in the application context.

Comment: unfortunately, if i define my class in app-context, it start to reload the app-context.xml in loop

Comment: There are other factors in play here. I can only make assumptions until you show us the context.

Comment: here is catalog with all config, it's in GITHub https://github.com/Amboss/ServerMonitoring/tree/master/src/main/resources UPDATED: I pushed it to synchronize all changes

Comment: @Serge I can't go through your code now, but it your application context seems fine to me (if you remove the `@Component`). Leaving the  `@Component` would have the context generate 2 beans of your type.